# List Path of Music

Tags: android, file, path

I want to create a list of song and his path. I wrote this code, but the app crash when I try to create the list. There is an error when I get the list from the file. How can I get the the path of my songs?

```
File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);

Toast.makeText(this, f.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



if (f.listFiles().length > 0) {
    for (File file : f.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
        Map<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
        song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

        songsList.add(song);
        Toast.makeText(this, song.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat (error list)  without that we can't help you.

Comment: f.listFiles() is Null and I don't know why